# apollo-client: How to insert a fragment in a gql template?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-client

I have this fragment:

```
// product-info.js
module.exports = gql`fragment productInfo on Product {
  id
  name
  model
  color
  quantity
}`
```

And I have this query:

```
// get-products.js
const productInfo = require('./fragments/product-info')

module.exports = gql`query getProducts {
  quote @client {
    items { ...productInfo }
  }
}`
```

This is not working because `...productInfo` is a simple literal here. 
Even string interpolation is not working `${...productInfo}`.

Comment: you don't have to keep it as modules - `.graphql` files can import framgents from other `.graphql` files - you didn't do your recent [homework](https://github.com/sysgears/apollo-universal-starter-kit/blob/master/packages/client/src/modules/post/graphql/PostQuery.graphql) ;)

Comment: (-_-) I saw it, but I just want to find out if the other way (with gql template) is possible. I always prefer to deal with .js files when possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include the string after the query, I don't know if it will work with `gql` tag, depends on your bundler settings:

```
module.exports = gql`query getProducts {
  quote @client {
    items { ...productInfo }
  }
}
fragment productInfo on Product {
  id
  name
  model
  color
  quantity
}`
```

Other options is include with string formatter:

```
const productInfo = require('./fragments/product-info')

module.exports = gql`query getProducts {
  quote @client {
    items { ...productInfo }
  }
}
${productInfo}`
```

Comment: OK, the first solution should work, but my point here is to share the fragment between queries, the the second solution, if working, will make it. But I finally opted for using .gql files and the `graphql-tag/loader` loader. Thank you.